# Can I develop an Android application using only LIBGDX without much knowledge of the components of the Android OS?

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx

I'm planning on developing a game for the Android market, and while I'm very experienced with Java and desktop gaming, I have almost no experience using Android. I heard about LibGDX which would simply let me distribute my game to Android with almost no additional effort beyond coding the actual game as I would a desktop game.

This seems almost too good to be true, can someone tell me whether there are any shortcomings of using LibGDX that I am unaware of (perhaps its buggy, complicates the process, or anything) before I start my project?

Thanks.

Comment: This is far too open-ended a question to answer constructively. libgdx allows you to develop cross platform, and in games, because you tend to not rely on native components, will work well. It's a framework, just like all the other ones like Unity, Cocos, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found Libgdx to be a great tool that enables rapid development of games for Android. This holds true if only for the simple fact that as opposed to needing to install my APK onto an Android device (or fire up an emulator) every time I want to run or debug my app, I can simply run the app in a window on my development PC.

For someone with limited knowledge of the Android SDK, Libgdx will help get you started. However, in the end you will need to become at least somewhat knowledgeable in the Android SDK in order to develop an app that is stable and of sufficient quality for release on the play store. Some things to keep in mind:

1. The hardware (e.g., GPU) on Android devices is not nearly as powerful as the hardware on your development machine. Thus, a demanding  graphical rendering that runs well on your dev machine might be too much for a typical Android device and bog down to unacceptable FPS. During development you should at least periodically upload your game to an Android device to see how it renders.
2. There are hundreds of Android devices on the market today, and you will need to find a way to test your game so that you can be sure that your game is compatable with the devices/OS versions you are targeting. (Google suggests that a beta release on the Android market is a good way to accomplish this).
3. At some point you will likely want to add Android-styled settings and other GUI styles that make you game conform to Android's pre-defined style conventions. (This makes your game look like an Android app and using the GUI APIs and styles Android already provides for you can save you time in the end).
4. There are significant differences between Android and pure Java in the way you should style your code for performance optimization (e.g., how to iterate over arrays, whether to use getters/setters or access fields directly). http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html will give you an overview on that.